# I can't install headset drivers

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, headset

I bought new headset (Razer kraken 7.1) and I have some issues with them. When I plug the headset into my PC, it tries to install 2 same drivers (kraken 7.1 drivers) but both fail. When I plug the headset into my laptop, 1 driver (kraken 7.1 driver) will download + the input and output driver will install correctly and my headset works good. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my PC?

I downloaded everything from Razer website but nothing helped, and contacted Razer support but they are not answering.

Comment: Did you make sure you downloaded the correct driver? Also, try installing the driver before you plug in the headset.

Comment: Try different USB ports, even the ones on the back of the PC.  Try http://www.devid.info  and see if there are any driver updates.  For example, for your USB port controller or etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to try to diagnose your problem.

Firstly - we need to know if its the headset or PC - does the headset work in another machin (if you have access to one)?  If your pc accepts other new hardware, or this headset doesnt work in another machine - its probably the headset at fault.

Next up - things to try:

- System restore ?
- Razer Synapse Drivers - Razer offer universal drivers (called synapse) alongside their "per-model" drivers - try these?
- Try disabling your antivirus and install again
- Try running a windows update and then reinstall the drivers
- Check the hardware has not been disabled in device manager by someone/something

If none of these get you anywhere, we can really start digging

Comment: This headset works on my laptop very good , just pluged in , waited 1 minute for finishing installation and worked.

Tell me more about system restore :D 
I used Razer Synapse 2.0 but still nothing happened
I did it yesterday but same issue .

Comment: Start > all programs > accessories > system tools > system restore.  It will reverse your systems state (registry, core files, few other bits and pieces) to the state they were in at an earlier time... very useful for debugging hardware and driver issues.   Don't worry though, it doesn't delete your files, they are stores separate to the stuff which is rolled back!

Comment: Oh yeah , i did it today but still nothing changed . Im just wondering why its installing 2 drivers and not complete anyone ..

Comment: because a headset is actuall 2 devices (mic and speaker) which is merely sharing a plastic coating.  Will keep looking and get back to you if i find any possible solutions

Comment: But at laptop it was installing only 1 driver , sound and mic at laptop work good..

Comment: The Razer Synapse 2.0 driver is not an all-in-one driver. It is a cloud based driver for devices that support it. http://www.razerzone.com/synapse2